# how to call a javascript function using asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

This is what i m trying. calling the function of the inline js. but i didn't working.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="javascript_Tutorials.WebForm1" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>javaScript Tutorials</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function objects() {
                alert("Well come");
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form runat="server" id="myform">
        <asp:Button onclick="<% objects(); %>" runat="server"  />
        </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and have the following error:

**CS1061: 'ASP.webform1_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'objects' and no extension method 'objects' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.webform1_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: I think you're looking for `onclientclick`. Anyway _"it doesn't work, here's my code"_ is not how it's done.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Button.OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx) instead on `onclick` to register client side javascript event and assign some id to button. The `onclick` is used to register server side event.

```
   <asp:Button  id="yourButtonID"  runat="server" OnClientClick="objects();" />
```

Comment: i have low reputation. thats why i couldn't give you the vote. but thnx a lot for urgent help...

Answer (score 1):

Try This>>

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>javaScript Tutorials</title>

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server" id="myform">
    <asp:Button onclick="<% objects(); %>" runat="server"  />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function objects() {
                alert("Well come");
            }
        </script>
```

Pasting script at last also works when above code does not works.

Answer (score 0):

You can you the following code:-

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClientClick="return objects();" runat="server"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove Parenthesis after function call

<asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClientClick="objects;" runat="server"  />
```